# Mass change the propety of multiple WORD files

Tags: php, ms-word

I have around 3500 microsoft word files and i notice that on some, the top margin and bottom margin are wrong! Right noe
Now, i can open all of the 3500 files, one by one, and change the property, or, and this is my question:
Is there an automatic way i could do this? Like a php script that opens the microsoft word file, checks the property and changes the property if it's not ok...

Is this feasable?

Comment: Check the word product documentation, there should be something like macros, office basic or similar. It should be equally simple like, let's say, writing some little PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a PHP library to handle word docs then it would make perfect sense.

I've not done it via PHP, but I have used Microsoft's "Office Interop" functionality to do similar things from C# (but in theory any other .NET language)